# Object Explorer Details SSMS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Object Explorer Details in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 is unable to perform a search

raising error: 
**Search failed: Failed to retrieve data for this request.**

Ideas?

Comment: Hard to say, but if you are just on SQL 2008, i would suggest updating the tools to the latest CU to see if that resolves anything.  Is there any other error in the stack as well?  Typically that is the last error to surface, but there are often times other errors below it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this may be a known glitch in Object Explorer.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2022833

At present it does not appear to have a fix.